# Spring Data findBy given Column 1 and In List Column2

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a requirement, where i want to find a list of Employees with given name and given surnames in list, something like this

```
findByNameAndSurnameIn(String name, List<String> surnames)
```

But, the above method is giving the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [null] did not match expected type

Any help, please suggest.

Comment: Well, as the message indicates, you're passing null for one of the arguments. Don't.

Comment: Could you please provide your entity

Comment: @JBNizet yes the parameter passed can be null also.

Comment: Then create a separate method, executing a different query, which does what you want in that case.

Comment: Can you clarify the desired result? 1. The param is ignored or 2. an `is null` condition is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring null fields is not possible in `spring-data-jpa`.

Here is a `JIRA` [ticket](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-209)which status is currently **investigation** by the `Spring` team.

[image: jira screenshot]

If you want to achieve then you can use a [***simple criteria query***](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/).